# Problem with running selenium script through the CLI

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Good day.

I have written selenium script which opens the site and then performs some actions. The script works perfectly in VSCode but I can't fire it in terminal. There is written that I have a syntax error in my code, although it works fine in IDE. The text of the syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
from Booking.booking import Booking
File "/Applications/VS_Code_projects/Selenium/Bot/Booking/booking.py", line 36
By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"a[data-modal-header-async-url-param*='selected_currency={currency}']"

                                                                                       ^
```

I tried to put single quotes instead of double quotes and vice versa but there is no result. Also I tried t reinstall Selenium on my PC.

Comment: Providing text instead of images helps to get faster recommendations from the community

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.